# publish to github with electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

when I test to publish on `github` I get this error `write ECONNRESET at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:87:16)`

Here is my code

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "publish": "electron-builder --publish always"
  },
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.3.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type" : "git",
    "url" : "https://github.com/Fizo55/app.git"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.fizo55.app",
    "productName": "app",
    "target": "NSIS",
    "directories": {
      "output": "build"
    },
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "github",
        "private": true,
        "owner": "Fizo55",
        "repo": "app",
        "token": "mytoken"
      }
    ],
    "nsis": {
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "oneClick": false
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test, it was my connection the problem, I switched on my 4G and now it work perfectly.